# error import plot_decision_regions from mlxtend.plotting

Tags: python, python-3.5, mlxtend

I have problems importing plot_decision_regions from mlxtend.plotting.

I have correctly installed mlxtend and I can import it in python3 without problems.

> > > from mlxtend.plotting import plot_decision_regions
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >         File "/home/marianna/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mlxtend/plotting/**init**.py", line 15, in 
> > >           from .heatmap import heatmap
> > >         File "/home/marianna/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mlxtend/plotting/heatmap.py", line 74
> > >           raise AssertionError(f'len(row_names) (got {len(row_names)})'
> > >                                                                       ^
> > >       SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, just upgrade your python version to 3.7 
the read error is in the file of mlxtend.plotting.heatmap.py where they use f-prefix for formating, a 3.7 feature.

```
conda install -c anaconda python=3.7
```